# Solve $x\ y\ dx=(y^3+x^2y+x^2)\ dy$ differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $x\ y\ dx=(y^3+x^2y+x^2)\ dy$ differential equation.

What I tried so far.

$M(x,y)=x\ y$ $N(x,y)=y^3+x^2y+x^2$

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=x$ $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=2x+2xy$

They are not equal so we need integrating factor.

$$\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}  }{N}=\frac{2xy-x}{y^3+x^2y+x^2}$$

so $$\mu(x)=e^{-{\huge \int}{\frac{(2xy-x)dx}{y^3+x^2+x^2y}}}$$

from here I can't continue.

EDIT.

I am getting $$\mu=|(1+y)\ x^2+y^3|^\frac{1-2y}{2+2y}$$

Comment: Note that you need to put the DE in the following form: $Mdx+Ndy=0$ Then check for exactness.

Comment: The DE $x\ y x'=(y^3+x^2y+x^2)$  is  homogeneous substitute $x=ty$ and $x'=t'y+t$.you end with a separable DE that is easy to integrate.

Comment: How you get $t^{\prime}$ there?Can you please elaborate more on that.

Comment: Differentiate  $x=ty$ with $t$ a function of $y$ $\implies x'=(ty)'=t'y+t$

Comment: @user577215664 It worked out.Thank you!

Comment: Thats' great.....and you're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$xydx=(y^3+x^2y+x^2)dy$$
$$x(ydx-xdy)=y(y^2+x^2)dy$$
$$(ydx-xdy)=\dfrac yx(y^2+x^2)dy$$
Divide by $y^2$:
$$d \left (\dfrac  {x}y \right)=\dfrac y x \left(1+\dfrac {x^2}{y^2} \right)dy$$
This is separable:
$$\dfrac  {du}{1+u}=2dy$$
With $u=\left (\dfrac  xy\right)^2$.

Comment: Thank you,this problem can't be solved using integrating factor?

Comment: You're welcome Yes you surely can find an integrating factor but it could be more complicated. The DE is homogeneous try to substitute $x=ty$  or  $y=tx$. @unit1991